# How to handle small but far-reaching implementation differences when inheriting (abstract) classes?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm a bit stumped on how to handle this.

Let's say I have the following abstract class of a websocket client and a subclass that implements most of its methods.
If instead of a command in a message, a websocket provider would need you to change paths (like `/ws/somesubscription` -> `/ws/othersubscription`). How would I go about and implement this without defining a new method in the subclass that would be otherwise almost the same?

My goal I want to achieve is to have my code remain dry, while having the flexibility of defining specific implementations.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from some_library import some_websocket_client

class WebsocketClientBase(ABC):

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_implementation_data = None
        self.some_other_data = None
        self.ws = None

    @abstractmethod
    def start_socket(self):
        self.ws = some_websocket_client()

    @abstractmethod
    def send_a_message(self, message):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def websocket_message(self, message_data):
        if not self.ws:
            self.start_socket()
        url = self.some_implementation_data['url']
        message = message_data['msg']
        command = message_data['ws_command']
        self.ws.send("{'command': {command}, 'message': {message}, 'url': {url}".format(command=command, url=url, message=message))
        some_websocket_client.send(message)


class SomeWSClient(WebsocketClientBase):
    # This subclass inherits almost everything, except its specific implementation data

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.some_implementation_data = {'url': 'some_url'}

    def start_socket(self, message):
        super().start_socket(message)

    def send_a_message(self, message):
        message_data = {
            "msg": "my message",
            "ws_command": "subscribe"
        }
        self.websocket_message(message_data)

    def websocket_message(self, message_data):
        super().websocket_message(message_data)


class ProblemWSClient(WebsocketClientBase):
    # Here I encounter problems

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.some_implementation_data = {'url': 'some_url'}

    def start_socket(self, message):
        super().start_socket(message)

    def send_a_message(self, message):
        message_data = {
            "msg": "my message",
            "ws_command": "subscribe"
        }
        self.websocket_message(message_data)

    def websocket_message(self, message_data):
        # I need to repeat this, because I can't call the superclass
        if not self.ws:
            self.start_socket()

        # Here I need to apply the new functionality, although largely the same.  
        command = message_data['ws_command']
        url = self.some_implementation_data['url'] + command
        message = message_data['msg']

        self.ws.send("{'message': {message}, 'url': {url}".format(command=command, url=url, message=message))
        some_websocket_client.send(message)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you can't use `super().websocket_message(message_data)` in your `class ProblemWSClient(WebsocketClientBase):`? `WebsocketClientBase` is also the superclass of `ProblemWSClient` just like `SomeWSClient` so I'm wondering why you can't use the same for `WebsocketClientBase`. P.S: I am new to Class inheritance so I might be asking a very naive question here. I have marked your question as favorite

Comment: @Bazingaa It's because it does something that's largely the same, just not what the implementation needs exactly. By calling super, you either execute the full function from the superclass, or else you wouldn't call it. So I have to be careful about how much I inherit and how much I leave to the specific implementation.

Comment: Why not inherit `ProblemWSClient(SomeWSClient)` and overwriting only diffs?

Comment: @stovfl My problem would still be that I need to rewrite the whole function while only a few elements of it are unique.

Comment: In your code, nothing is different! Whatsoever, you could use a `class method` doing the few unique things.